# Where is the go project working directory when using modules?

Tags: go, go-modules

I am trying to download, make some tweaks and build a golang project from GitHub. The project's instructions are:

```
go get github.com/<vendor>/<projectName>
cd src/github.com/<vendor>/<projectName>
go build .
```

That used to work in the past — before enabling Go Modules.

Now I have `GO111MODULE=on` (go version `go1.15.4 linux/amd64`). When running the first command, go downloads the project as a module and all its dependencies.

But then there is no `src/github.com/<vendor>/<projectName>` folder anymore. Moreover, the is no folder named `<projectName>` *anywhere* in the system.

Instead, there is folder `pkg/mod/github.com/<vendor>` which contains the project folder with weird symbols in its name (exclamation marks etc.) and version identifiers.

How do I get the project folder available for making tweaks and builds?

Comment: https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules

Comment: @ScottStensland I saw that and did not find answer to my question. Where exactly is it in there? I can't be bothered to learn the whole bloody thing if all I want is just to make a few tweaks and build one project.

Comment: To checkout the source use git clone.

Comment: @Volker Should that be done instead of `go get` or in addition to?

Comment: Instead. `go get` is for adding a dependency in module mode.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by @Volker, good old `git clone` should be used.

It turns out that it should be used *instead* of `go get github.com/<vendor>/<projectName>` (no idea why the project vendor recommends that):

```
git clone git://github.com/<vendor>/<projectName>
cd <projectName>
go get ./...
# do tweaks here
go build .
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is tweaks, the easiest way it use to use `go mod vendor`.
https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-vendor

> The go mod vendor command constructs a directory named vendor in the main module's root directory that contains copies of all packages needed to support builds and tests of packages in the main module

Comment: Please elaborate. If just run that, I get `go: cannot find main module; see 'go help modules'`.